# SQL query to calculate a flag based on the row value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

TableA is a superset that has 1000 rows and TableB is a subset that has 500rows. Structure of both tables is same with ID and Empno.  Write a SQL query that should result ID, Empno, flag(Y/N) shows Y if row in Table B is already present in TableA else flag shows N

TABLE A

```
 id emp
 1  a
 2  b
 3  c
 4  d
```

TABLE B

```
id empno 
1  a
2  b
3  f
4  g
```

Resultset

```
id empno flag
1  a      Y
2  b      Y
3  f      N
4  g      N
```

```
select id, empno , ?case statement on id in table b as flag ??
from table b
```

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: select id, empno , ?case statement ??

Comment: OK, so what do you think should go into the case statement?

Comment: if eid in (select id from table a) then flag =y else flag = N ...am i right...am new here,,sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an outer join and a check for NULL

```
select a.id, a.empno, 
       case when b.id is null then 'N' else 'Y' end as flag
from table_a a
   left join table_b b on a.empno = b.empno;
```

The above will show your for each row in table_a if it exists in table_b.

If you **only** want to see rows from table_b you could use something like this:

```
select id, empno, 
       case 
          when (select count(*) from table_a a where a.empno = b.empno) = 1 
               then 'Y' 
          else 'N'
       end
from table_b b
```